# What technology to use to send data/Ethernet (about 128 kbps) over copper cable (4km)?

Tags: communication, ethernet, transceiver, modem

What thechnologies can i use to send data/ethernet (w/ a symmetrical traffic throuput of about 128kbps) over copper cable (4km)?

1)SHDSL would be an option !!(but I couldn't find any chip with datasheet that would allow my design to go on)

2)On the other hand SHDSL rates are very high. Isn't there a simpler technology/solution that would allow low to medium rates over copper cable?

3)ADSL technologies could be attractive as their chips should be cheap. But the asymetric nature of the tranceiver makes it unlikely to be usefull, since the adsl modem chip@CPE is slinked to a DSLAM chip at CO side(as fas as I know). Is there any adsl(DSLAM) single channel chip OR any solution that would allow the xDSL variants to be used?

4)other technologies (any hint is highly appreciated)??

Regards

Comment: 128kbps over 4km of copper is only a low rate by the standards of the xDSL era - and everything from the 56k standards onwards has been biased towards having different types of kit at each end of the link.

Comment: I recognize that your question is specific to copper cable, but is there a reason why you cannot consider fiber optic cable?

Comment: This is the throughput of a basic ISDN T1 link. What about this technology? Disclaimer: I never used that, I don't know what would be the complexity. When I quickly tried to have a glance at some transceiver chips datasheets, I started having nausea.

Comment: @Steve: deploying fiber optic cable would be harder and not always/everywhere available.

Comment: @Dean: having different types of chips at each end of the link would not be a problem as long as chips are affordable. I suspect that for SHDSL the chips at the 2 sides are the same (only their sw configurations differ). I believe in case of ADSL the DSLAM chips are available in high capacities (since they are deployed at the CO in a central fashion providing service for many clients)

Comment: @Dim: thanks for your suggestions but aren't these chips obsolete??

Comment: ISDN is clearly decaying, but there are still chips available, and it's not going to completely die soon either. See for example mouser, in the "Telecom Interface ICs" range. There are quite a few chips available from various manufacturers, but most are expensive and seem hard to interface.

Comment: Choose a decent coax or twisted pair and look at its data sheet for attenuation and losses. See what can be achievable. If I can send 660 Mbps over 50 m then 660 kbps (a thousand times lower) should be doable with decent cable over many, many km.

Comment: @Andy: using normal telephony wires (that might be used in normal SHDSL solutions) is a target. You shouldn't expect me to lay out 4km of my own cable.

Comment: If no other viable solution can be found, isn't there an SHDSL chip with the info/datasheet required to make a design? (Lantiq, now Intel chips provide no datasheet)

Comment: I don't expect anything other than clear facts.

Comment: Unclear how it does with the tradeoff of "longer cable than spec" and "lower data rate than spec", but RS485 might be worth a look. 4000 feet (not meters) and 10Mbit/s is the spec. A bit more than 3x the length at 80 times slower? Who knows?

Comment: [Track down a couple of PairGain modems](http://m.ebay.de/itm/PAIRGAIN-CAMPUS-T1-HDSL-Modem-/181511069797) and attach them to your ethernet network at each end.  1.5MBit over 6km.  They can be gotten used for about $30 US on ebay.

Answer (score 2):

RS485 would be my first shot for an electrical layer, but do 8b10 line coding or such so you can transformer or capacitor couple to avoid common mode problems (it has a limited common mode range), hell biphase might be ok at 250KHz edge rate over that sort of distance, maybe with a 1:4 transformer at each end if using telecom grade wire, and makes the PLL for clock recovery easy.

The real gotchas with this are actually things like common mode and transient protection to make the link electrically reliable when EFTs happen.

4km over good quality wire at that sort of speed is actually not that hard, and something like cat 5 counts as good quality wire at those speeds, phone line complete with dirty water filled splices and poor pair balance inducing noise from every other ADSL circuit in the 100+ pair bundle, not so much.

Push comes to shove, QAM16 with a dac, power amp (ADSL line driver) and adc should get it done with a symbol rate low enough to work over that range.

Answer (score 0):

Might be possible to build yourself a pair of "Winmodems" (simple transcievers which do QAM in software) then implement [V.300](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.300/en) or similar.

The SDR community may be able to help you as well.